# Query to return related results, but still a row if no related rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider the relationship of Person owns Car owns Wheels.

Tables:
Person
  PersonID
  PersonName

Car
  CarID
  PersonID  (fkey to person)
  CarName

Wheel
  WheelID
  CarID (fkey to Car)
  Position

I need a query that shows me all the wheels that belong to a person, and if there are no wheels, I still need a single row with the persons name.

```
Sally 
  Car 1
    Wheel 1
    Wheel 2
  Car 2
    Wheel 3
  Car 3
   <no related wheels>

Bob
   <no related cars>
```

The query should return the columns PersonName, CarName, Wheel.Position

I want the results to be:

```
Sally, Car 1, Wheel 1
Sally, Car 1, Wheel 2
Sally, Car 2, Wheel 3
Bob, null, null
```

I need it to be a T-SQL query, and would prefer no dynamic SQL.

I tried

```
select p.PersonName, c.CarName, w.Position
from Person p
left join Car c on c.PersonID = p.PersonID
left join Wheel w on w.CarID = c.CarID
```

But this does not work as I get an extra result:
`Saly, Car3, null`. Using `left outer` gives the same problem.

Comment: and the sample data is what? and the attempted query you have is where? what are the table names? what are the column names? *how about a few facts to work with?*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name, c.id, w.id
  FROM person p, car c, wheel w
 WHERE p.id = c.id_person
   AND c.id *= w.id_car

         SELECT p.name, c.id, w.id
           FROM person p, car c
LEFT OUTER JOIN wheel w ON c.id = w.id_car
          WHERE p.id = c.id_person
```

Based on the additional info added to the question, the query would be:

```
         SELECT p.id, cw.id_car, cw.id_wheel
           FROM person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.id as id_car, c.id_person, w.id as id_wheel
                   FROM car c, wheel w
                  WHERE c.id = w.id_car) cw
             ON p.id = cw.id_person;
```

Comment: that's T-SQL.  I don't know what you are talking about.  I'll add the SQL though

Answer (score 0):

Just left join the three tables together, something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.PersonName,
    t1.CarID,
    t2.WheelID
FROM People t1
LEFT JOIN Cars t2
    ON t1.CarID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN Wheels t3
    ON t2.WheelID = t3.ID;
```

Comment: just wrong.  it needs to be an outer join and this only works for people that own a single unicycle

Comment: @AbdulAhad Left join and left outer join are synonomous AFAIK.  And my query is a reasonable guess given the limited information we have.

Comment: removed the minus.  it's just wrong, the foreign key relationship is backwards and both of the joins can't be outer joins